# I can't find my ISO/ZIP file for step 2 in the universal usb installer process

Tags: 12.04

I can't seem to finish the universal USB installer process.
Step 2 say; I need to select my ubuntu-12.10*desktop*.iso

where can i find that, as I have already downloaded Ubuntu but I think it is for the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

The ISO is probably in `/home/user/Downloads`.  That's where all download go by default, unless you have saved it somewhere else.

If that is the case, then you can search for the file.  To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
find $HOME -name '*.iso'
```