# where can I find an iso file to be burned on usb?

Tags: usb-drive

I want to creat abootable usb flash but can't find an iso file- pls.help me where to find this file so as to get start whith your fine software
best regards

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/325167/i-cant-find-my-iso-zip-file-for-step-2-in-the-universal-usb-installer-process/325172#325172

Answer (score 0):

You can download the iso file here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download

To make it into a bootable disk on windows there is this guide: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

(At the right side of the link above there's a guide for mac too)